# Ĉu ekzistas Esperanta versio de la Fundamenta Gramatiko?

Tags: grammar, fundamento

La [Fundamento de Esperanto](http://www.akademio-de-esperanto.org/fundamento/) havas [parton pri gramatiko](http://www.akademio-de-esperanto.org/fundamento/gramatiko.html) de Esperanto.

Ĝi estas en [la franca](http://www.akademio-de-esperanto.org/fundamento/gramatiko_franca.html), [la angla](http://www.akademio-de-esperanto.org/fundamento/gramatiko_angla.html), [la germana](http://www.akademio-de-esperanto.org/fundamento/gramatiko_germana.html), [la rusa](http://www.akademio-de-esperanto.org/fundamento/gramatiko_rusa.html) kaj [la pola](http://www.akademio-de-esperanto.org/fundamento/gramatiko_pola.html) kaj enhavas preskaŭ la saman enhavon en ĉiuj tiuj lingvoj.

Ĉu ekzistas oficiala aŭ kvazaŭ-oficiala traduko de tiu gramatiko al Esperanto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PMEG havas [ĉapitron](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/aldonoj/fundamenta_gramatiko.html) pri la gramatiko en la Fundamento kun [kompleta traduko](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/aldonoj/fundamenta_gramatiko.html#i-z6c) de la 16 reguloj.

Answer (score -1):

Se vi iras al lernu.net, vi povas ŝanĝi la lingvon en la agordoj ... kaj poste vi povas legi la retejon en Esperanto.

Comment: Bonvenon ĉe [esperanto.SE] Stack Exchange! La [gramatiko de lernu.net](https://lernu.net/eo/gramatiko) ja estas havebla en pluraj lingvoj (inter ili ankaŭ Esperanto mem), sed ĝi havas nenian indikon, kiuj el iliaj partoj estas Fundamenta kaj kiuj ne, ĉu? Kaj ĝi vere ne estas rekta traduko de la Fundamenta Gramatiko (t.e. la regularo en [la libro "Fundamento de Esperanto"](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamento_de_Esperanto)).

Comment: @Clement, bonvolu prilabori kaj kompletigi vian respondon ekz. laŭ observoj de das-g.